# reverse array issue in VueJs

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

i get conversations message via facebook graph api and i need to reverse data.

in computed reverseChat function i try return `this.chat.data` works but not reverse() when i try `JSON.parse(this.chat).data.reverse()` or `this.chat.data.reverse()` error showing.

console show error

```
[Vue warn]: Error when rendering anonymous component at C:\Users\PEM\Desktop\src\components\Chat.vue:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at json.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.render (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2430), <anonymous>:123:85)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (ever at <anonymous> (app.js:606), <anonymous>:2464:21)
    ...
```

sample code in jsfiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/pqrf2vu4/
```

Comment: what to do you mean by reverse? Please, take a time to explain better your needs and problem

Comment: You appear to be trying to reverse an object.  `reverse()` needs to be used on an array.  Why are you reversing `chat`?  Are you maybe trying to reverse the `data` array inside of chat instead?

Comment: You're having a json string in your chat property. Parse it then you can access the data property. `JSON.parse(this.chat).data.reverse()`. Please have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pqrf2vu4/1/). (Please update your question, so the problem is clear and I'll add an answer.)

Comment: i'm added picture error to my question, i want result reverse like your link    i try `JSON.parse (this.chat) .data.reverse ()` in .vue but error.

Comment: Hi Pe m! Can you edit the question, remove the linked image and paste in the error message as text?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick ok, i paste error message as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(this.chat).data.reverse()
```

works. See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzkLen3o/)

Comment: In jsfiddle works but in file.vue my project error I don't know why

Comment: Maybe it does not have data in `this.chat` when it is computing? give `this.chat` a default value of `{data:{}}` see if that works.

Comment: actually this - `chat: '{"data": [] }'`

Comment: in computed reverseChat function i try return `this.chat.data` works but not reverse() when i try `JSON.parse(this.chat).data.reverse()` or `this.chat.data.reverse()` error showing.

Comment: try doing `return this.chat && this.chat.data ? this.chat.data.reverse() : ''` in `reversedChat()`

Comment: it works!! Could you please explain that? thank you.

Comment: Two things to explain. First, vue calculates the values in `computed` when it is initialized & whenever the variables changes. When it is initializing, `chat` is probably empty, because you are pulling the data from the api. It gave you the error, because it was doing `JSON.parse([])` while it was initializing.
Second, the code I wrote above, checks if `chat` or `chat.data` is null or not - if it is null, returns `''` & if not, returns `this.chat.data.reverse()`